# Random faces in render mode

Tags: rendering, faces

I'm working on making a very basic table design and want to use it to make a reference image using the render mode however when I go into the mode random faces appear in two spots on the object. I tried fixes normal's, and un-hiding invisible objects neither worked, I deleted the top face only to find an empty inside, I don't know what could be wrong since I'm still very new to this please ignore the lighting and various other things needing to be fixed.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps add the file?

Comment: I've added the blend file, sorry like i stated above new to this and forgot to put it on, and didn't know how to.

Comment: after checking the blend file I added to see if it was the most recent save, it wasn't, I found it didn't load the table top texture and didn't have the faces in the render, I put the texture on again and the faces reappeared

Comment: after redoing the texture, annoying but needed fixed anyway, the faces disappeared and it works fine now. so no clue what happened but I know the problem was something to do with the texture, for anyone who might have this happen to them